# Python Numba - Convert DataFrame series object to numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numba

I have a pandas dataframe with strings I am trying to use the `set` operation using python `numba` to get the unique characters in the column that contains strings in the dataframe. Since, `numba` does note recognize pandas dataframes, I need to convert the string column to an `numpy` array. However, once converted the column shows the `dtype` as a `object`. Is there a way that I could convert the pandas dataframe (column of strings) to a normal array (not an object array)

Please find the code for your understanding.

```py
z = train.head(2).sentence.values #Train is a pandas DataFrame
z
```

Output:

```py
array(["Explanation\nWhy the edits made under my username Hardcore Metallica Fan were reverted? They weren't vandalisms, just closure on some GAs after I voted at New York Dolls FAC. And please don't remove the template from the talk page since I'm retired now.89.205.38.27",
       "D'aww! He matches this background colour I'm seemingly stuck with. Thanks.  (talk) 21:51, January 11, 2016 (UTC)"],
      dtype=object)
```

Python Numba code:

```py
@njit
def set_(z):
    x = set(z.sum())
    return x

set_(z)
```

Output:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-9d5bc17d106b> in <module>()
----> 1 set_(z)

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    342                 raise e
    343             else:
--> 344                 reraise(type(e), e, None)
    345         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    346             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    656             value = tp()
    657         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 658             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    659         raise value
    660 

TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.ArgConstraint object at 0x7fbe66c01a58>:
--%<----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 491, in new_error_context
    yield
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 194, in __call__
    assert ty.is_precise()
AssertionError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 138, in propagate
    constraint(typeinfer)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/typeinfer.py", line 195, in __call__
    typeinfer.add_type(self.dst, ty, loc=self.loc)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/errors.py", line 499, in new_error_context
    six.reraise(type(newerr), newerr, tb)
  File "/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/six.py", line 659, in reraise
    raise value
numba.errors.InternalError: 
[1] During: typing of argument at <ipython-input-50-566e4e12481d> (3)
--%<----------------------------------------------------------------------------


File "<ipython-input-50-566e4e12481d>", line 3:
def set_(z):
    x = set(z.sum())
    ^

This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 0: Unsupported array dtype: object

This is not usually a problem with Numba itself but instead often caused by
the use of unsupported features or an issue in resolving types.

To see Python/NumPy features supported by the latest release of Numba visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html
and
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

For more information about typing errors and how to debug them visit:
http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/troubleshoot.html#my-code-doesn-t-compile

If you think your code should work with Numba, please report the error message
and traceback, along with a minimal reproducer at:
https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/new
```

Would anyone be able to help me in this regard.

Thanks & Best Regards

Michael

Comment: What is sum supposed to be doing on an array/list of strings?  What do you hope to acomplish with this numba?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I wan to sum of all strings in each cell and find unique values. The column has more than 220,000 rows (cells) . It takes a while.

Comment: With a bit of testing, that `sum` just concatenates all the strings into one.  Plain `set` on that finds all the unique characters, a large subset of 'A-Za-z'.  `njit` on `set` does work with a list of numbers.  It does not work with a string or list of strings.

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply. So what you are saying is that `njit` does not work for strings? It's ok then. May be it's just a limitation of `numba`. Will check other fast computation libraries of python for more inf.  Thanks & Best Regards